# How to avoid multiplying of a string which precedes <<noweb reference>> in code block?

Tags: org-mode, tangle, noweb

When <> expands to multiple line and I wrote like this

`some-string <<noweb ref>>`

then it expands like

`some-string line1-from-noweb-ref
some-string line2-from-noweb-ref
some-string line3-from-noweb-ref`

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: What are you trying to avoid exactly? The behaviour you describe is normal. Do you want `some-string` to appear only on the first line? Or not at all? A minimal reproducible example would help clarify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're asking how to prefix only the first line of the noweb block. It will probably depend on the language your using, but I came up with this hack for bash:

```
#+NAME: example
#+BEGIN_SRC text
 please echo this line
 date ## but not this one
 cd test ## this one
 ls -l ## or this one  
#+END_SRC

Bad source code block, echo prepended to very line:

#+BEGIN_SRC bash :noweb yes :results verbatim
  echo <<example>>
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: please echo this line
: date
: cd test
: ls -l
: 

Good source code block, echo prepended to the first line only, the rest
are executed:

#+BEGIN_SRC bash :noweb yes :results verbatim
  echo \
  <<example>>
#+END_SRC

 #+RESULTS:
 : please echo this line
 : Thu Nov  9 10:22:32 EST 2017
 : total 0
 : -rw-r--r-- 1 tws tws 0 Nov  9 09:44 one
 : -rw-r--r-- 1 tws tws 0 Nov  9 09:44 three
 : -rw-r--r-- 1 tws tws 0 Nov  9 09:44 two
```

Comment: Thank you! Seems like a solution. But why do you think is "The behaviour you describe is normal. " ? For me <<>> looks like usual _inline_ macros. Well, don't you wait that for example in JS `somestring ${nowebref()}` do the same - multiply somestring as many as nowebref() will return rows ?

Comment: I only mean that according to the orgmode manual, the designed behaviour is for some-string to be prepended to each line. I don't have an opinion on whether this is the best behaviour, but it is the intended behaviour of the orgmode authors

Comment: Ahh, I see now! I should better RTFM :) By the way, inspired with such behaviour I am trying one trick with <<>> but stuck again. May be you could see with one eye? It's here https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/36832/how-to-pass-newline-n-string-to-noweb-call